# How do I use ROW_NUMBER()?

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-number

I want to use the `ROW_NUMBER()` to get...

1. To get the `max(ROW_NUMBER())` --> Or i guess this would also be the count of all rows

I tried doing:

```
SELECT max(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY UserId)) FROM Users
```

but it didn't seem to work...

2. To get `ROW_NUMBER()` using a given piece of information, ie. if I have a name and I want to know what row the name came from.

I assume it would be something similar to what I tried for #1

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY UserId) From Users WHERE UserName='Joe'
```

but this didn't work either...

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 179):

For the first question, why not just use?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable
```

to get the count.

And for the second question, the primary key of the row is what should be used to identify a particular row.  Don't try and use the row number for that.

---

If you returned Row_Number() in your main query,

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by Id) AS RowNumber, Field1, Field2, Field3
FROM User
```

Then when you want to go 5 rows back then you can take the current row number and use the following query to determine the row with currentrow -5

```
SELECT us.Id
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS Row, Id
     FROM User ) us 
WHERE Row = CurrentRow - 5
```

Comment: In my situation I'm given a UserId, and I want to get the UserId that's a certain number of rows back.
What if a row gets deleted?
In that case, I can't just go UserId - offset, because then I wouldn't get the right record.

Comment: Its better to use select count(1) from mytable to select the count of records. This so quick and efficient

Answer (score 53):

Though I agree with others that you could use `count()` to get the total number of rows, here is how you can use the `row_count()`:

1. To get the total no of rows:

   ```
   with temp as (
       select row_number() over (order by id) as rownum
       from table_name 
   )
   select max(rownum) from temp
   ```
2. To get the row numbers where name is Matt:

   ```
   with temp as (
       select name, row_number() over (order by id) as rownum
       from table_name
   )
   select rownum from temp where name like 'Matt'
   ```

You can further use `min(rownum)` or `max(rownum)` to get the first or last row for Matt respectively.

These were very simple implementations of `row_number()`. You can use it for more complex grouping. Check out my response on [Advanced grouping without using a sub query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968305/advanced-grouping-without-using-a-sub-query/968983#968983)

Comment: Could you please explain how to choose the column, used in `order by X`? In other words, how should `X` be determined? Thanks!

Comment: @KevinMeredith: The `order by X` is the order you will use to determine the order in which the rows will be assigned `ROW_NUMBERS()`. Remember that tables in relational databases, despite their name, don't have a formal ordering, so if you want to call a row "1" or "10" or "1337", you need to order them first using an `ORDER BY` clause, which is the one that goes in the `OVER (ORDER BY X)` clause.

Answer (score 27):

If you need to return the table's total row count, you can use an alternative way to the `SELECT COUNT(*)` statement.

Because `SELECT COUNT(*)` makes a full table scan to return the row count, it can take very long time for a large table. You can use the `sysindexes` system table instead in this case. There is a `ROWS` column that contains the total row count for each table in your database. You can use the following select statement:

```
SELECT rows FROM sysindexes WHERE id = OBJECT_ID('table_name') AND indid < 2
```

This will drastically reduce the time your query takes.

Comment: You are right about the full table scan, but note that it is not necessarily a clustered index scan, as it might use a non-clustered index for that

Comment: Also this is true only for Sql-Server, as other RDMBS have optimized the select count

Answer (score 14):

`ROW_NUMBER()` returns a unique number for each row starting with 1. You can easily use this by simply writing:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 'Column_Name' DESC) as ROW_NUMBER
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use this for get first record where has clause

```
SELECT TOP(1) * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY UserId) AS rownum 
FROM     Users 
WHERE    UserName = 'Joe'
ORDER BY rownum ASC
```

Answer (score 7):

May not be related to the question here. But I found it could be useful when using `ROW_NUMBER` -

```
SELECT *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 100)) AS Any_ID 
FROM #Any_Table
```

Answer (score 6):

```
select 
  Ml.Hid,
  ml.blockid,
  row_number() over (partition by ml.blockid order by Ml.Hid desc) as rownumber,
  H.HNAME 
from MIT_LeadBechmarkHamletwise ML
join [MT.HAMLE] h on ML.Hid=h.HID
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT num, UserName FROM 
 (SELECT UserName, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY UserId) AS num
  From Users) AS numbered
WHERE UserName='Joe'
```

Comment: To enumerate __all__ rows -- otherwise you're just enumerating the rows where the username is Joe, which is not the goal;-).

Comment: @Matt:  Call me a pedant; I tend to prefer either "derived table" or "anonymous view" to the term "sub select".

Comment: @adam, as I'm a pedant too -- would "nested select" make you happier? I don't like to use terms such as table or view when no `TABLE` or `VIEW` keyword is around... but `SELECT` sure is!-)

Comment: @Alex: you present a valid point.  "Nested select" works great for me :)  By the way, I really enjoy reading the anecdotes you add to your comments and answers.

Comment: @Adam, thanks! Sometimes my answers are very bare code, as here, but I do love to flesh them out when I do have a spare minute;-).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Row_Number` for limit query result.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    select row_number() OVER (order by createtime desc) AS ROWINDEX,* 
    from TABLENAME ) TB
WHERE TB.ROWINDEX between 0 and 10
```

--
With above query, I will get PAGE 1 of results from `TABLENAME`.

Answer (score 2):

If you absolutely want to use ROW_NUMBER for this (instead of count(*)) you can always use:

```
SELECT TOP 1 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id)   
FROM USERS  
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Need to create virtual table by using `WITH table AS`, which is mention in given Query.

By using this virtual table, you can perform CRUD operation w.r.t `row_number`.

QUERY:

```
WITH table AS
-
(SELECT row_number() OVER(ORDER BY UserId) rn, * FROM Users)
-
SELECT * FROM table WHERE UserName='Joe'
-
```

You can use `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` in last sentence by in spite of `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Row_Number() function](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-row_number-over-partition-by-order-by.aspx) is to sort and assign an order number to data rows in related record set. So it is used to number rows, for example to identify the top 10 rows which have the highest order amount or identify the order of each customer which is the highest amount, etc.

If you want to sort the dataset and number each row by seperating them into categories we use Row_Number() with Partition By clause. For example, sorting orders of each customer within itself where the dataset contains all orders, etc.

```
SELECT
    SalesOrderNumber,
    CustomerId,
    SubTotal,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerId ORDER BY SubTotal DESC) rn
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
```

But as I understand you want to calculate the number of rows of grouped by a column. To visualize the requirement, if you want to see the count of all orders of the related customer as a seperate column besides order info, you can use [COUNT() aggregation function with Partition By clause](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-count-function-with-partition-by-clause.aspx)

For example,

```
SELECT
    SalesOrderNumber,
    CustomerId,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerId) CustomerOrderCount
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
```

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY UserId) From Users WHERE UserName='Joe'
```

will return all rows where the `UserName` is `'Joe'` UNLESS you have no `UserName='Joe'`

They will be listed in order of `UserID` and the `row_number` field will start with 1 and increment however many rows contain `UserName='Joe'`

If it does not work for you then your `WHERE` command has an issue OR there is no `UserID` in the table. Check spelling for both fields `UserID` and `UserName`.