# SSRS - How to total a row

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

```
Report Month         Booked Month          Hours     Available Hours    Reported Hours
2015-12-01 00:00:00 2015-10-01 00:00:00     3.5       97                   172
2015-12-01 00:00:00 2015-10-01 00:00:00     0.75      97                   172
2015-12-01 00:00:00 2015-10-01 00:00:00     6.85      97                   172
2015-12-01 00:00:00 2015-10-01 00:00:00     3         97                   172
2015-11-01 00:00:00 2015-10-01 00:00:00     3.5       97                   185
2015-11-01 00:00:00 2015-10-01 00:00:00     0.75      97                   185
2015-11-01 00:00:00 2015-10-01 00:00:00     6.85      97                   185
2015-11-01 00:00:00 2015-10-01 00:00:00     3         97                   185
```

In my SSRS report i want to total the Reported Hours Column. This person booked 172 hours in December and 185 hours in November so his total for the year should be 185 + 172 = 357.

In my current report it adds together all the rows. How do i get it to just pick one row of reported hours per month?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's not a set way to do this in SSRS.

Usually you would wrap your query in another query that uses **ROW_NUMBER** and group by months. Then only add the hours if the row_numnber = 1.

[How do I use ROW_NUMBER()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961007/how-do-i-use-row-number)

Unfortunately that's not always possible. I wrote some code to add up unique records based on another field. I made it to get check amounts for various vendors.

For the expression, you would use:

```
=Code.SUMVendors(Report_Month & "|" & Fields!Reported_Hours.Value)
```

Add the Visual BASIC to the **CODE** of the report:

```
FUNCTION SUMVendors(BYVAL ITEMS AS OBJECT()) AS DECIMAL
'Returns Sum of unique vendors. Use as Code.SUMVendors(Vendor & "|" & Amount)
IF ITEMS IS NOTHING THEN 
    RETURN NOTHING
    GOTO EXITSUB
END IF

DIM TEMP AS STRING
DIM VENDORS AS STRING = ""
DIM VENDOR AS STRING = ""
DIM VALUE AS DECIMAL 

FOR EACH ITEM AS OBJECT IN ITEMS

    TEMP = CONVERT.TOSTRING(ITEM)

    VENDOR = "|" & LEFT(TEMP, InStr(TEMP, "|"))

    VALUE = CDEC(MID(TEMP, InStr(TEMP, "|") + 1, LEN(TEMP)))

    IF InStr(VENDORS, VENDOR) = 0 Then  
        VENDORS = VENDORS + VENDOR 
        SUMVendors = SUMVendors + VALUE
    End If

NEXT

EXITSUB:
END FUNCTION
```