# For each category (A field), I would like the top ten types (another field) by count

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have a table that looks like this:

```
+------------+-------------+-------+
|  Category  |    Type     | Count |
+------------+-------------+-------+
| Fruits     | Apple       |    13 |
| Vegetables | Carrot      |     7 |
| Legumes    | Kidney Bean |     1 |
| Fruits     | Orange      |     1 |
| Vegetables | Green       |     3 |
| Legumes    | Black Bean  |     1 |
| Vegetables | Leek        |     1 |
| Fruits     | Banana      |     1 |
| Legumes    | Lentil      |     1 |
| Fruits     | Mango       |     1 |
| Fruits     | Pinapple    |    18 |
| Fruits     | Strawberry  |     1 |
| Legumes    | Flat Bean   |     2 |
| Vegetables | Brocolli    |     8 |
| Fruits     | Rambotan    |     1 |
| Fruits     | Marang      |    15 |
| Vegetables | Cauliflower |     5 |
| Vegetables | Aubergine   |     1 |
+------------+-------------+-------+
```

For each category, I would like the top ten types by count.

Given the table in question is actually millions of rows, if I simply did a `select category, type, sum(Count) group by category, type order by category, type` then I would get results where the type was not in the top ten.

I'm using postgresql but believe there's likely a more "general" sql way of doing this. Is there?

Comment: check this - https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/03/12/select-top-n-per-group-postgresql/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select Category, Type, Count from (
    select your_table.*, row_number() over(partition by Category order by Count desc) as rn
    from your_table
) t
where rn <= 10
```

This gives exactly 10 rows (if exists) for each `Category`, with highest `Count` column.

If you want top 10 result "with ties", then use `rank()` function instead of `row_number()`

Comment: Please explain your answer sir

Comment: Hey it works! Thank you very much. What is over(partition... doing?

Comment: @DougFir - Glad to help, here is explanation about window functions https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html

Answer (score 0):

U can use rank,row number and dense_rank

[Link to dense rank and rank description](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/en/book_rank_dense_rank_functions.html)

[row_number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961007/how-do-i-use-row-number)